# Why does a CloudWatch request count alarm created via CloudFormation yield "Insufficient Data"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) for my application and am trying to make a request count alarm via a respective template. I can successfully make the request count alarm directly for the [Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), but the alarm state within [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) is  "insufficient data", when I'm trying to achieve the same via a CloudFormation template.

My ELB JSON is:

```js
"ElasticLoadBalancer": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": {
      "Fn::GetAZs": ""
    },
    "Listeners": [
      {
        "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
        "InstancePort": {
          "Ref": "WebServerPort"
        },
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      }
    ],
    "HealthCheck": {
      "Target": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "HTTP:",
            {
              "Ref": "WebServerPort"
            },
            "/"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "HealthyThreshold": "3",
      "UnhealthyThreshold": "5",
      "Interval": "30",
      "Timeout": "5"
    }
  }
},
```

My alarm JSON is:

```js
"StatisticAlarmLow": {
  "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
  "Properties": {
    "AlarmDescription": "Alarm if there are too many unhealthy hosts.",
    "MetricName": "RequestCount",
    "Namespace": "AWS/ELB",
    "Statistic": "Sum",
    "Period": "60",
    "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
    "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold",
    "Threshold": "1500",
    "AlarmActions": [
      {
        "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
      }
    ],
    "Unit": "Count",
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},

"StatisticAlarmHigh": {
  "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
  "Properties": {
    "AlarmDescription": "Alarm if there are too many unhealthy hosts.",
    "MetricName": "RequestCount",
    "Namespace": "AWS/ELB",
    "Statistic": "Sum",
    "Period": "60",
    "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
    "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold",
    "Threshold": "4000",
    "AlarmActions": [
      {
        "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
      }
    ],
    "Unit": "Count",
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

From the above it generates the alarm with "insufficient data" as a state. Can anybody tell me what could be the reason? And if there is any sample/example template available for using request count alarm on ELB, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) fragment alarm fragment of your [Amazon CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) template seems okay, but your [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) fragment contains a presumably incorrect dimension, insofar it references an *AutoScalingGroupName* named *WebServerGroup* - this isn't a supported dimension as per section *Dimensions for Elastic Load Balancing Metrics* on page [Monitoring Your Load Balancer Using CloudWatch](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_MonitoringLoadBalancerWithCW.html), stating *Elastic Load Balancing data can be aggregated along any of the following dimensions*:

- **LoadBalancerName** - *Limits the metric data to Amazon EC2 instances that are connected to the specified load balancer.*
- **AvailabilityZone** - *Limits the metric data to load balancers in the specified Availability Zone.*

Comment: Thank you, Steffen Opel. I have changed the dimensions and it works.